# how to get multiple variable values using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using ajax to get data from my Mysql database. The data is about in 10k rows so I need pagination in my page. I get a pagination code online and it is working fine without ajax but I am unable to make it functional with my ajax code.

here is my pagination file "function.php" and I have no issue with that

```
<?php
   function displayPaginationBelow($per_page,$page){
       $page_url="?";
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount from pdbp inner join bp on(pdbp.bp_id=bp.id) where bp.status= 1";
        $rec = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total = $rec['totalCount'];
        $adjacents = "2"; 

        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

        $prev = $page - 1;                          
        $next = $page + 1;
        $setLastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $setLastpage - 1;

        $setPaginate = "";
        if($setLastpage > 1)
        {   
            $setPaginate .= "<ul class='setPaginate'>";
                    $setPaginate .= "<li class='setPage'>Page $page of $setLastpage</li>";
            if ($setLastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $setLastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $setPaginate.= "<li><a class='current_page'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                  
                }
            }
            elseif($setLastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $setPaginate.= "<li><a class='current_page'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                  
                    }
                    $setPaginate.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$setLastpage'>$setLastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                elseif($setLastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $setPaginate.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $setPaginate.= "<li><a class='current_page'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                  
                    }
                    $setPaginate.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$setLastpage'>$setLastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                else
                {
                    $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $setPaginate.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    for ($counter = $setLastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $setLastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $setPaginate.= "<li><a class='current_page'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                  
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
                $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$next'>Next</a></li>";
                $setPaginate.= "<li><a href='{$page_url}page=$setLastpage'>Last</a></li>";
            }else{
                $setPaginate.= "<li><a class='current_page'>Next</a></li>";
                $setPaginate.= "<li><a class='current_page'>Last</a></li>";
            }

            $setPaginate.= "</ul>\n";       
        }


        return $setPaginate;
    } 
?>
```

here is my ajax file in which i am getting data through database and sending it to my view file.

```
<?php 
include_once('config/connection.php'); 
// here is the Pagination code starts
include_once "function.php";

    if(isset($_GET["page"]))
    $page = (int)$_GET["page"];
    else
    $page = 1;

    $setLimit = 10;
    $pageLimit = ($page * $setLimit) - $setLimit;

                  // Pagination code ends

if(isset($_GET['name'])){
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 $retval = "";
 $pagination = "";
 $counter = 0;
$query = mysql_query("select id,card_name,phone1,address,region,country,cert_num,category_cod,material_cod,trade_type,web from pdbp inner join bp on(pdbp.bp_id=bp.id) where bp.status= 1 and card_name like '%$name%' limit $pageLimit , $setLimit");

 while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $id = $data['id'];
     $name = $data['card_name'];
     $phone1 = $data['phone1'];
     $region = $data['region'];
     $trade_type = $data['trade_type'];
     $address = $data['address'];
     $web = $data['web'];
     $queryr= mysql_query("select Region from regions where RegionId = '$region'");
                                $region_1 = mysql_fetch_array($queryr);

                                 $region_name = $region_1['Region'];

     $country = $data['country'];
        $queryc= mysql_query("select Country from countries where CountryId = '$country'");
                                $country_1 = mysql_fetch_array($queryc);

                                 $country_name = $country_1['Country'];




     $cert_num = $data['cert_num'];
     $cn=explode(",",$cert_num);
     $cns = "";
        foreach($cn as $cc){

              $cert_fetch = mysql_query("select description from cert where id='$cc'");
                                        $cert_fetch1 = mysql_fetch_array($cert_fetch);
                                        $cnum = $cert_fetch1['description'];
                                    $cns=$cns."<div style='margin:5px;display:block;clear:both'> ".$cnum." </div>";

                                }

    $cat = $data['category_cod'];
        $category = explode(",",$cat);
        $cc = "";
        foreach($category as $categories){
                                $categories_fetch = mysql_query("select subc_name, category_name, line from sub_categories as s inner join product_categories p ON (p.category_cod = s.pc_Cod) inner join product_line l ON (p.line_cod = l.line_cod) where subc_cod='$categories'");
                    $aaa = mysql_fetch_array($categories_fetch);

                    $s = $aaa['subc_name'];
                    $cname = $aaa['category_name'];
                    $l = $aaa['line'];

                            $cc=$cc."<div style='margin:5px;display:block;clear:both'> ".$s.'-'.$cname.'-'.$l." </div>";

        }


            $mat = $data['material_cod'];
        $material = explode(",",$mat);
        $mm = "";
        foreach($material as $materials){
                                $material_fetch = mysql_query("select material from product_material where material_cod='$materials'");
                        $mat_fetch1 = mysql_fetch_array($material_fetch);
                                        $mcod = $mat_fetch1['material'];
                                        $mm=$mm."<div style='margin:5px;display:block;clear:both'> ".$mcod." </div>";

            }



     $retval=$retval."<tr><td>".++$counter."</td><td> ".$name." </td><td> ".$phone1." </td><td> ".$address." </td><td> ".$region_name." </td><td> ".$country_name." </td><td> ".$cns." </td><td> ".$cc." </td><td> ".$mm."</td><td> ".$trade_type."</td><td> ".$web."</td><td></tr>";
 }

echo $retval;



 }
 ?>
```

I am getting data successfully but Now I need to echo displayPaginationBelow($setLimit,$page); to show pagination below the data,which is coming through function.php and I have no idea how to do this.

and here is my jquery code:

```
$("#cmp_name").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
             'url':"filter.php",
            'data':{name:$("#cmp_name").val()},
            'method':'GET',
            'success':function(name){

                 $("#data").html(name);         
            }
        })

  });
```

Anyone know how to achieve this. Kindly help me out or if someone give some more efficient way to achieve my goal I will be very gratefull. Secondly I know I am using mysql_* which is deprecated and I will fix it soon

Answer (score 0):

use type instead method while using ajax

```
$("#cmp_name").keyup(function(){
    name = $("#cmp_name").val();
    $.ajax({
         'url':"filter.php",
        'data':{"name":name},
        'type':'POST',
        'success':function(data){

             $("#data").html(data);         
        }
    })
```

});

Answer (score 0):

use array for multiple return value.

in filter.php

```
$retval['data'] = YOUR_PREVIOUS_RETVAL;
$retval['pagination'] = displayPaginationBelow($setLimit,$page);
echo json_encode($retval);
```

in javascript

```
$("#cmp_name").keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
         'url':"filter.php",
        'data':{name:$("#cmp_name").val()},
        'type':'GET',
        'dataType':'json',
        'success':function(result){
             $("#data").html(result.data);         
             $("#PAGINATION").html(result.pagination);
        }
    })
});
```

you must specify dataType to 'json'.